# Find all possible solutions of the simultaneous equations x × y = (1 , 0 , 0) x · ( − 1 , 2 , 0) = 1 x · y = − 1

Tags: calculus

Find all possible solution of the simultaneous equations

$\vec x \times \vec y$ = (1,0,0)

$\vec x \cdot$ (-1,2,0) = 1

$\vec x \cdot \vec y$ = -1

My attempt:

Let $\vec x$ = (a,b,c) and $\vec y$ = (d,e,f)

$\vec x \times \vec y$ = bf - ce, cd - af, ae - bd = (1,0,0)

$\vec x \cdot$ (-1,2,0) = -a + 2b = 1

$\vec x \cdot \vec y$ = ad + be + cf = -1

so now I have these equations:

bf - ce = 1

cd - af = 0

ae - bd = 0

-a + 2b = 1

ad + be +cf = -1

This is where I'm stuck. I think I need to put it into linear system form but I don't know how to approach that way. Also, it seems like the unknowns could be just 0 or 1 but there's too many possibilities to try.

Answer (score 0):

Substitution looks like the way to go.  Note that you have five equations in six unknowns, so one combination will not be determined.  Your next to last gives $a=2b-1$, so you can eliminate $a$ in all of them.